# version tag in appengine-web.xml & https

Tags: google-app-engine, https

So far, I have been working on version 1 of my server application. I could reach the application at
    https://myappid.appspot.com

using my browser. (Note: I am using https, not http)
Now, I am changing the the version id to 2 (version 1 is now production, version 2 is next gen release and I would like to test that). I need version 1 to remain the default version for the users are using the stable, production version.
Now that I have 2 versions, I tried to reach version 2 static front page from by browser (Chrome) using
    https://2.latest.myappid.appspot.com
as per the instructions I could find. Instead chrome gives me the following error
*You attempted to reach 2.latest.myappid.appspot.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.appspot.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of 2.latest.myappid.appspot.com.
You cannot proceed because the website operator has requested heightened security for this domain.*

This problem goes away for     http://2.latest.myappid.appspot.com
I have requested secure connection through web.xml's

<transport- guarantee> element. So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try 2.myappid.appspot.com.

Also, in the Admin Console when you click on Versions, you can see all versions of your app. A number of each version is a link - you can click on it to get access to that version running.

If you try to access the new version using https, you should use the following instead:

https://2-dot-myappid.appspot.com/

Comment: Same story @Andrei. http works, not https. btw, should have mentioned I have only java servlet front ends in this app.

Comment: you are absolutely right. It gives me the URL I expected (& as you correctly pointed out), it is https and every browser I have tried complains of the certificate being wrong. I can't explain it.

Comment: Your SSL certificate only covers the main domain (myappid.appspot.com). You can ignore these warnings from browsers. This is explained in AppEngine documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need 2 live versions of the same app?

Although possible with some limitations, this is not what the system was designed to do. The https is apparently one of these limitations.

If you want version 2 to *replace* version 1, than all you need to do is "set default" on version 2, and than it will be the one mapped to https://myappid.appspot.com

Comment: I am trying to field test version 2

Comment: if you can't live with http for testing, you can open another appengine instance just for that, and make it default so you can use https with that. A bit hassle if you need the real live datastore, though.